# Solving the package dependency list automatically for building ubuntu touch

Tags: 14.04, ubuntu-touch, cross-compilation

I'm following the guide in [XDA Link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-9/general/guide-linux-nexus-9-t2985958) to install `nexus 9` device with Ubuntu touch. But I'm stuck in the installation of tool-chain and cross compiler. I am stuck in the following

```
 sudo apt-get install gcc g++ git gcc-4.9-aarch64-linux-gnu g++-4.9-aarch64-linux-gnu libncurses5-dev
```

Throws error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'gcc-4.9-aarch64-linux-gnu-base' for regex 'gcc-4.9-    aarch64-linux-gnu'
E: Unable to locate package g++-4.9-aarch64-linux-gnu
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'g++-4.9-aarch64-linux-gnu'
```

So, I am downloading the required packages and installing manually using `dpkg`
Is there any shortcut for this?

I tried using `gdebi`. But did not help much.

I am using ubuntu 14.04-64 as host machine.

Comment: what it's not working with that command?

Comment: @AlexGreg : edited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the command with this one:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc g++ git gcc-*-aarch64-linux-gnu g++-*-aarch64-linux-gnu libncurses5-dev
```

On your system you don't have `gcc-4.9-aarch64-linux-gnu`. The above command will install the last actual version on your system

Comment: with the command, `aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc-4.8` was installed. Is it okay to use older version ?

Comment: yes..it's working for me :-)